# How to have Soundcloud player play uninterrupted across page loads using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to make a music blog, and have a music player embedded in my navigation bar. Presently I'm doing this in rails, and I know that I can use JQuery to accomplish this. Unfortunately my implantation is not right. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong. I've added my application, and header file.

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
 <title><%=full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                          'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' ,  'data-turbolinks-track' => true  %>

<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">      
</script>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#content').load('home.html.erb');
     $('a').on('click', function(){
     var page = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#content") .load('static_pages/' + page + '.html');
    return false;
      });
     });


  </script>

   <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>


    </head>

    <body>


   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div class= "container">

  </div>
  <% if notice %>
   <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>

  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
 <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
 <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

</body>

</html>
```

header.html.erb

```
  <div id = "navbar">
  <ul id = "menu-nav">


  <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "home"  > <i class="fa fa home">   </i> Home </a> </li>
 <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa fa-music"></i>  Music </a> </li>

 <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "about" >  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>   Artist Discovery </a> </li>

 <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>  News </a> </li>

  <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>  Alex! </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the JS file with the soundcloud stuff?

Comment: I don't have a js file, because I found external file weren't running properly or my implementation wasn't proper. That's why I have script in my html file. The iframe I was going to wrap in a div, and add it to the ul.                  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#content').load('home.html.erb');
     $('a').on('click', function(){
     var page = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#content") .load('static_pages/' + page + '.html');
    return false;
      });
     });
  </script>

Comment: Your js now will reload the player each time the page changes which is why you are experiencing this behavior.  I think you want to either put the iframe in the layout so it doesn't get refreshed or set the JS object to a variable on the document.window.